How to illustrate that the solution of $du=u(1+W)dt$ is ${\mathcal F}_t$ adapted?
Set a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal F,P)$, and a one dimension wiener process $W$ on it, with filtration ${\mathcal F}_t=\sigma({W(s)|0 \le s \le t})$ which is generated by the wiener process.
When we consider such equation
\begin{equation}
(1)\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
du= u(1+W)dt \\
u(0)=1
\end{array}\right.
\end{equation}
Obviously, we can solve this question on some ODE environment, for fixed $\omega \in \Omega$, we can solve
\begin{equation}
(2)\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
\displaystyle\frac{du}{dt}= u(1+W(\cdot,\omega)) \\
u(0)=1
\end{array}\right.
\end{equation}
on $[0,T^*]$, here $T^*$ is the constant depend on $\omega$ because the right side of the equation,
\begin{equation}
f:R^1 \times R^+ \times \Omega \rightarrow R^1
\\
f(x,t,w)=x(1+W(t,w))
\end{equation}
$f$ satisfies some locally lipschitz condition
$$
|f(x_1,t,w)-f(x_2,t,w)| \le (1+\sup_{0\le s \le t}W(s,w))|x_1-x_2|
$$
and we can extend this solution from $[0,T^*]$ to $[0,+\infty)$, by a priori estimate
$$
\displaystyle\frac{d|u|^2}{dt}= 2|u|^2(1+W(\cdot,\omega)),
$$
and the gronwall inequality.
So by the above steps, we can obtain a binary mapping
\begin{equation}
u:[0,+\infty) \times \Omega \rightarrow R^1
\end{equation}
where $u(\cdot,\omega)$ is the solution of $(2)$, after adjust a zero measure set in $\Omega$.
${\bf What \, I \, want \, to \, ask \, is}$:
Whether the mapping
$
u(t,\cdot): \Omega \rightarrow R^1
$
is ${\mathcal F}_t$ measurable?
The problem arise when we want to approach it by iteration method, even in a inteval suffcient close to $0$.
For instance, if we set, for $t \in [0,T']$
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{ll}
u_0(t,w) = 1  \\
u_{k+1}(t,w) = 1 + \int_0^t f(u_k(s,w),s,w) ds
\end{array}
\end{equation}
Then, for arbitrary small T' we choose, the convergence property of $u_k$ can't be ensure for each $\omega$, because the lipschitz constant of $f$ vary with $\omega$, and it could be arbitrary large.
@ zhoraster
point out that we can solve this question explicitly, because u satisfies
\begin{equation}
\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
\displaystyle \frac{du}{u}= (1+W)dt \\
u(0)=1
\end{array}\right.
\end{equation}
Integral both sides, we can get that u is ${\mathcal F}_t$ measurable.
But I wonder on some more complex condition, for example
\begin{equation}
\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
du= u(1+W)+Wdt \\
u(0)=1
\end{array}\right.
\end{equation}
or other condition that we can't get an explicit expression of u.
That is:

for a.e $\omega$, we can solve the ODE like $(2)$, and extend it to $\infty$
the locally lipschitz constant vary with $\omega$, and could be arbitrary large
term of $W$ on right side of the equation is ${\mathcal F}_t$ adapted

Can the ${\mathcal F}_t$ measurable property of u be hold?

You can solve the equation explicitly. Then it's pretty obvious that the solution is adapted.

@zhoraster How to solve it explicitly? The right side of the differential equation is relevent to u itself.

Start with dividing the equation by $u$.

You are right. If there are other methods on some more complex condition when dividing them by u wouldn't work?

One can only answer specific questions. Not "If there are other methods on some more complex condition when dividing them by u wouldn't work?"

Thanks， my fault.

The equations
$$u'=u(1+W)\text{ and } v'=v(1+W)+W$$
have the exact solutions Solution to General Linear SDE
$$u(x)=u(0)exp(\int_{0}^{x} 1+W(s) ds),$$
and
$$v(x)=v(0) exp\left( \int_{0}^x (W(s) + 1) ds\right) + exp\left( \int_0^x (W(s) + 1) ds\right) \cdot\int_0^x exp\left(- \int_0^r (W(s) + 1) ds\right) W(r) dr.$$
Therefore, we indeed get $\mathcal{F}_{t}$-adapted.
